# jQuery datatable checkbox checked not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am trying to use checked. checked property in jQuery datatable based on record selection and want to pass it to server side for further processing. Here is a prototype of what I am trying to do. Kindly advise what could be wrong here. https://live.datatables.net/wobekake/3/edit

js file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".select-checkbox").click(function(){
            if($(this).prop("checked") === true){
                console.log("Checkbox is checked.");
            }
            else if($(this).prop("checked") === false){
                console.log("Checkbox is unchecked.");
            }
        });
  //excluding the first column its for checkbox.. so
  $('#example tfoot th:not(:first)').each(function() {
    var title = $(this).text();
    $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" />');
  });
  $('#example').DataTable({
    columnDefs: [{
      orderable: false,
      className: 'select-checkbox',
      targets: 0
    }],
    select: {
      style: 'multi',
      selector: 'td:first-child'
    },
    
 
    order: [
      [1, 'asc']
    ],
    initComplete: function() { //add here only the search part


      // Apply the search
      this.api()
        .columns()
        .every(function() {
          var that = this;

          $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change clear', function() {
            if (that.search() !== this.value) {
              that.search(this.value).draw();
            }
          });
        });
   
      //alert("Hi : " + $(this).find("td").eq(2).html());   
    }
    
    
  });
});
```